# How to connect OpenCV to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, opencv

The path:

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
```

Outputs such an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in main.o
      cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to fix this error?